# Automake Yacc Output Filename Quandary

Tags: c++, makefile, yacc, bison, automake

**Problem:**

I have a project which I'm porting from Solaris/Lex/Yacc to Linux/Flex/Bison + Autotools.
I'm running into the following issue, and I wonder if anyone out there knows how to get around it. Given a target like so (only necessary details included):

```
bin_PROGRAMS=my_prog

my_prog_YFLAGS=-d
my_prog_SOURCES=\
   main.cpp \
   parser.ypp \
   scanner.lpp
```

Automake is generating the following source files from the lpp and ypp:

- scanner.lpp -> scanner.cpp (as per Automake manual)
- parser.ypp -> **my_prog**-parser.cpp and **my_prog**-parser.h (why?)

**Attempted Solutions:**

Using bison's -b and -o options to alter output file names. The problem with this is that **automake** appears to assume default output names (parser.tab.c) and *move* the files with a script. If I alter the output file names with bison, the build fails when automake attempts to rename the files that aren't there.

Is there some option or something I am missing?

Comment: Don't fight the system - you end up losing.

Comment: Just a note: you can accept your own answer so this question looks finished.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution**:

So it took me actually reading through the automake source itself (for the curious, look at the **handle_single_transform** function). If there are per-target options specified for a given source-type, automake automatically prepends the project name to any generated files.

Therefore, changing:

```
my_prog_YFLAGS=-d
```

to

```
AM_YFLAGS=-d
```

Causes automake to properly generate rules causing parser.ypp to generate:

- parser.cpp
- parser.h